# how to un-init NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, git-bash, npm-init

So oddly I really cannot find the answer to this question and after a few posts and docs I've looked at on NPM I've decided to ask the question - which may be a very basic one but doesn't seem to be implicitly addressed...

How do you uninstall npm from a dir?

Premis:

you `npm init -y` on the wrong directory

desired outcome:

to remove npm from that directory

I'm working on windows 10 / using git bash on VS code terminal

any help here would be appreciated -

Wally

Comment: delete .node_modules and package.json

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All `npm init` does is setting up `package.json` for you (guided or not). If you just `del package.json` from the wrong directory, you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi Kamen - thanks for the answer - such a basic solution, I would have thought that npm init would have done something more behind the scenes, so is npm init even necessary - or could you just create a package.json file manually?

Comment: It's the same, `npm init` is just a way of doing it through the CLI. If you call it with `-y`, it will just init with default values with no other input from you, otherwise it will go through the needed params and ask you to input values.

Comment: '-f' or '-y' ... ok thank you for the input - I know its a very basic question

Comment: Not sure if I'm looking at the right thing, but it seems that all four (`-f`, `--force`, `-y`, `--yes`) are the same: https://github.com/npm/init-package-json/blob/latest/init-package-json.js#L18

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the `package.json` from the wrong directory should do the trick.

You will have to keep in mind that if in case you have run the `npm i` or `npm install` commands after `npm init` you will also have to delete the `node_modules` folder (as it usually takes plenty of disk space) and run `npm i` now in the correct directory.

Comment: Agree, leaving node_modules directory is not a good idea.